# How to find the specific component a React warning is referring to?

Tags: reactjs

This is what I see in my console:
[image: console warning]

In my React project, I'm seeing many warnings that look like this:

```
Warning: <React warning>
  in div
  in div
  in form (created by MyComponent)
  in MyComponent
  in div
  ...
```

Is there any way to figure out which component the warning is specifically referring to?

I have installed React Dev Tools but it has not helped me figure out which component these warnings are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the React documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#component-stack-traces), detailed stack traces can be added with the babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source)